# Targeting row in database

Tags: sqlite

i am having trouble targeting a specific row in my database

I want to be able to select from table contacts WHERE rownumber = 5(for example)

```
  select * from Contacts WHERE RowNum = 5
```

This doesn't work , however it should select data where the rownumber is 5.

EDIT: This is now fixed , the correct code was :

```
("select rowid, * from Contacts WHERE rowid = $num+1")
```

Comment: Can you provide the column name name of your table?

Comment: Do you mean `ROWID = 5`?

Comment: Is that the column name of that number?

Comment: Sorry, rowid didnt work , my table is contacts and my column name is name

Comment: I fixed it , for anyone who is interested i had to use this                                               
    ("select rowid, * from Contacts WHERE rowid = $num+1")

Answer (score 0):

Although you have found a solution that works; using the **rowid** may be fraught with ongoing issues.

- There is a reliance upon the list being presented according to the order of the **rowid** which would not necessarily be acceptable to a user.
- The **rowid** column is not guaranteed to monotonically increase (although highly likely unless you reach the 9223372036854775807th row).
- The **rowid** will not reflect the nth row if rows are deleted, the **rowid** will remain as it was but a VACUUM (cleanup) will renumber the **rowid**'s.
- If the highest existing **rowid** is 9223372036854775807 then an attempt will be made to assign a random value that is unused when a new **rowid** is assigned (a new row is inserted).

The above is true if there is no alias of the rowid. If there is then the behaviour in regard to VACUUM is that the **rowid** values will be retained and thus not renumbered.

- defining a column using `column_name INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` is how a column is made an alias of the **rowid**

  - If the **AUTOINCREMENT** keyword is used (*it can only be used for a column that is an alias of the **rowid** column*). Then the behaviour is again different in that the a new **rowid** has to be higher than the highest **rowid** ever used (rather than the highest existing). If the **rowid** 9223372036854775807 has been used then a new row cannot be inserted and an SQLITE_FULL error will be issued.

Typically the nth position is wanted when a list is presented e.g.

```
Alan
Mary
Bert
Sue
Fred
Jane
Zac
Louise
```

Then Fred is the 5th in the list or the element at offset 4 of an array and hence **rowid** 5 will be Fred **IF the data was inserted in the above order**.

However, if the list were ordered by name then it would be presented as :-

```
Alan
Bert
Fred
Jane
Louise
Mary
Sue
Zac
```

If considered from the **rowid** perspective the list would be

```
1 (Alan)
3 (Bert)
5 (Fred)
6 (Jane)
8 (Louise)
2 (Mary)
4 (Sue)
7 (Zac)
```

So now Fred is 3rd but using `WHERE rowid = 3` would select Bert not Fred.

Deleting any row but the last row (without ordering) introduces a discrepancy between the equation `rowid = number in list`.

The intended use of **rowid** is to identify a specific row rather than to be an anticipated value. In all the above scenarios the complications can be eliminated by presenting the list but to have a parallel array of the **rowid**, so when selecting Fred as offset 4 then, offset 4 into the parallel array yields a value of 5.

Comment: Thank you for this, i have since found this out when deleting things from my table (im not very experienced with databases) could you please suggest a solution that would work even when i delete rows in the middle of the data? Would be much appreciated

Comment: @JamesDraper the last paragraph is how you could manage this one way (i.e. have an associated array with the respective **rowid** (perhaps a list of objects)). Another would be to use `your_query_to_get_the_list ...... LIMIT offset,1` where offset is 0 for the first row, 1 for the 2nd etc (as per you original determination of rownumber) and that the query is ordered as per the list from which the selection is being made.